# Exist a tool that read the WSO2 ESB APIs definition and automatically creates the Swagger documentation?

Tags: wso2, swagger, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am not so into **WSO2 ESB** and I have the following doubt.

I am using **WSO2 EI** containing **WSO2 ESB** product. I am using the ESB to developr some REST API.

My question is: exist some tool\plugin that starting from the APIs definition into the ESB creates the swagger documentation for these APIs? I don't mean the WSO2 API Manager, I am not using it at this time but something that read the APIs defined into the ESB and create the Swagger documentation.

If exists something like this what have I to do to install and use it?

Thank you